# Как создать seed, чтобы вставить 100 записей?

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте. Если сидер,который должен заполнять таблицу users.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => str_random(10),
            'email' => str_random(10).'@gmail.com',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Но он генерирует только одну запись. Мне надо, чтобы он сгенерировал 100 юзеров.  Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте цикл

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function run()
    {
       for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => str_random(10),
            'email' => str_random(10).'@gmail.com',
        ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Блин, как просто. Спасибо большое. Что-то сразу не дошло.